# TIme bind parameter command error *influxql.StringLiteral are not compatible

Tags: influxdb, influxql

Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong in my command below which gives the error shown below?

Command:

```
eCollection=( $(cut -d ',' -f2 new.txt ) )

start=   date  --utc +%FT%T.%2NZ

sleep 10

end=  date --utc +%FT%T.%2NZ

for i in "${eCollection[@]}"
do

  var=$((var+1))

  if [[ $var -gt 1 ]] ; then

    curl -G 'http://localhost:8086/query?db=telegraf' --data-urlencode \ 
    'q=SELECT * FROM '$i' WHERE "time" >= $timebegin AND "time" \
     <= $timeend' --data-urlencode  \ 
    'params {"timebegin":"${start}","timeend":"${end}"}'

  fi

done
```

Error:

```
{"results":[{"statement_id":0,"error":"invalid operation: time and *influxql.StringLiteral 
are not compatible"}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an update that has to do with working with strings

```
start=$(date  --utc +"%FT%T.%2NZ")

    sleep 100

end=$(date  --utc +"%FT%T.%2NZ")

startCall='"'$start'"'
endCall='"'$end'"'

echo "$startCall"

echo "$endCall"

for i in "${eCollection[@]}"
do

  var=$((var+1))

  if [[ $var -gt 1 ]] ; then

echo ${i}

 curl -G 'http://localhost:8086/query?db=telegraf' --data-urlencode 'q=SELECT * FROM '$i' WHERE "time" >= $timebegin AND "time" <= $timeend' \
 --data-urlencode 'params={"timebegin":'$startCall', "timeend": '$endCall'}'

  fi

done
```